# How to get the value in URL parameter? xmlhttp.status returns 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am a beginner programmer, using Javascript and PHP. I have a page of buttons, and I am trying to `ahref` the buttons to their respective vendordetails.html page. After reaching the vendordetails.html, a php code will run to `SELECT * where vendorid = $vendorid` and display * in html page.
**My situation**
When I click on button #2, the url sending over looks like this:

```
http://servername/..../vendordetails.html?vendorid=2
```

On ^ page, I can receive the '2' from the URL parameter using the `getUrlVars()` function.
(`alert(decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["vendorid"])); // alerts the value '2'.`)

However, when I make the Ajax call, `xmlhttp.status` returns **'500'** instead of 200, meaning that theres a internal server error, and the parameters sent might be incorrect. I heavily suspect that it is my php codes but simply cannot find any mistakes (it is similiar to the working display button php file), and I would like to find some guidance!

**vendordetails.html**

```
var vendorid = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["vendorid"]);
alert(decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["vendorid"])); //alerts 2

function displayvendordetails(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = serverURL() + "/vendordetails.php";
  url += "?vendorid=" + vendorid.trim(); 
  //also tried using ?vendorid = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["vendorid"])
  alert(url); //alerts http://servername/..../vendordetails.php?vendorid=2

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    //alert(xmlhttp.readyState); alerts 4
    alert(xmlhttp.status); //alerts 500
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      alert("hello working"); //not alerted, code stops working after if statement
      getdisplayResult(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function getdisplayResult(response){
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var i;      

  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[0].vendorname.trim() != ""){
      vendorname = arr[0].vendorname;
      //var vendorname; declared outside
      $("#vendorname").html(arr[0].vendorname);
    }

    if (arr[0].vendortype.trim() != ""){
      vendortype = arr[0].vendortype;
      //var vendortype; declared outside
      $("#vendortype").html(arr[0].vendortype);
    }

    if (arr[0].rebatepercentage != ""){  
      $("#rebatepercentage").html(arr[0].rebatepercentage + "%"); 
    }       
  }       
}

displayvendordetails();

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
  return vars;
}
```

**vendordetails.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$vendorid = $_GET['vendorid'];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT vendorname, vendortype, rebatepercentage WHERE vendorid = '" . $vendorid. "' ");

$outp = "[";

while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}

    $outp .= '{"vendorname":' . $rs["vendorname"] . ',';

    $outp .= '"vendortype":"' . $rs["vendortype"] . '",';

    $outp .= '"rebatepercentage":"' . $rs["rebatepercentage"] .

    '"}';

}

$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
```

That php code should return:

```
[{"vendorname":"Test","vendortype":"Apparel","rebatepercentage":"20"}, {...}, {...}]
```

Additional note:
1. Please keep the ajax call w/o jQuery as I am familiar with that format more.
2. `serverurl()` is defined in a global js file and I have confirmed it to be correct

Comment: If you go into your PHP error log, are there any errors? You can find out where errors are logged to by executing `var_dump(ini_get('error_log'));` and PHP will output it to your browser. Also make sure error logging is enabled by executing `var_dump(ini_get('log_errors'));`.

Comment: My Telco is having a problem islandwide, so I cannot login to my server to change my php code right now! Will try this when I wake up!

Comment: still trying to get it to echo will get back to you soon

Comment: Never ever create your own json manually. Use json_encode() on an array or object. You to need to implement error output and inspect the actual request in browser dev tools to see what it says or check your error logs on server. 500 means an error in your server side code. Also easy to open a GET right in browser address bar and see the output.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!! the problem ended up being really embarrassing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect SQL statement, it should be
"SELECT vendorname, vendortype, rebatepercentage FROM Vendors WHERE Vendorid =".$vendorid);

Answer (score 0):

Might not be entirely helpful, but if you use Chrome you can right-click > Inspect > Network and then with this open you can re-executhe the ajax page and you will see all http requests, their type, status and response, when the ajax is finished click on "Stop recording". You can examine the HTTP headers of the ajax GET request and see if they are as expected. If they are fine, the issue must be with the php/server.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input! I cant seem to find the ajax GET request row for 'vendordetails.html', but there is one on my other working page, 'profiledetails.html' and it looks [like this](http://imgur.com/a/9sF6r). So ideally I want my ajax GET request role to have a status of 200 right

Comment: Click on the top request for vendordetails to see inside it, check that the url for the GET is correct, if yes, check if the response is as you expected similarly to [link](http://pasteboard.co/5u3bnvtjB.png)